# Display items from an input file

Tags: c, arrays

This program scans numbers from an input file.

In this case, the numbers are: 
    23
    353
    626
    5
    14
    25
    86
    95
    44
    47
    55
    26
    30
    14
    12
    25
    28
    47
    895
    4255

The user can choose to display as many numbers as they want.

If the user wants to display the first 3 numbers then 23, 353 and 626 should be displayed.

The following code displays no numbers.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void FillArray(FILE *fp, int n, int num[]);

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    FILE *outPtr;

    int num[20];
    int i;
    int number = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    fptr = fopen("numInput.txt", "r");

    FillArray(fptr, number, num);

    for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", num[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + num[i];
    }
    outPtr = fopen("resOut.txt", "w");
    fprintf(outPtr, "The Sum is %d", sum);

    fclose(fptr);
    fclose(outPtr);

    return 0;
}

void FillArray(FILE *fp, int n, int num[])
{
    int count = 0;
    printf("How many number? ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (count = 0; count < n; count++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &num[count]);
    }

}
```

Comment: you should remove this line: "#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"

Comment: @BodoThiesen Why?  If you're using Visual Studio and don't want a bunch of useless warnings it's necessary.

Comment: There ain't no thing as "useless warnings". If you believe otherwise, give one example, then we can discuss, why that warning is not useless.

Comment: @BodoThiesen `warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.`  Multiply that by a fair number of completely safe when used properly functions and you see why it's useful to disable them when writing platform independent code.

Comment: there needs to be a check of the count gotten from the user to assure that it is in the range 0...20

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: `sprintf` is almost always wrong. Use `snprintf` instead. If VC doesn't have that, `#define snprintf sprintf_s`, then it has it. Warnings are there for a reason. Don't just ignore that. And `sprintf` can always be replaced by `snprintf` and if it can't then `sprintf` is an error anyways. BTW: The NSA likes `sprintf` very much - should be enough reason for anyone else to not like it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare (in your code):

```
int number = 0;
```

with (commented by me)

```
FillArray(fptr, number, num);     /* FillArray() will receive only COPIES of arguments */

for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", num[i]);
}
```

How many times will body of this loop execute?

(**Hint:** The function `FillArray()` has *no chance* to change the value of `number`, so it is still `0`.)

> **Recommended fixes (guaranteed) - based on using a *pointer* to `number`:**

```
void FillArray(FILE *, int *, int *);        /* Insert explicit declaration in main() */
                                             /*    - only for my satisfaction ;-)     */

FillArray(fptr, &number, num);               /*      &number  instead of  number      */

void FillArray(FILE *fp, int *n, int num[])  /*        *n     instead of     n        */

    scanf("%d", n);                          /*         n     instead of    *n        */

    for (count = 0; count < *n; count++)     /*        *n     instead of     n        */
```

(and consider using **plural** in your prompt `"How many number? "`)

Comment: Please consider voting my answer, too (click on triangle up arrow) if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Because "number" variable can't be redefined this way. When you call function like this you assign "n" local function variable `n=number;`, inside function "n" got redefined and after function execution value of "n" is discarded. If you want to redefine variable in function you need to do like this:

**1) As a return value**

```
int FillArray(FILE *fp, int num[]){
    int n,count = 0;
    printf("How many number? ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    ...
    return n; 
}
```

then call function:

```
number = FillArray(fprt, num);
```

**2) Pass the pointer to a value**

```
void FillArray(FILE *fp, int* n, int num[]){
    int count = 0;
    printf("How many number? ");
    scanf("%d", n);
    ...
    for (count = 0; count < *n; count++)
    ...
 }
```

function call:

```
   FillArray(fptr, &number, num);
```

Edited: Thx to Bodo.

Comment: and use it like this: "*n" (in the for loop)